# Is it possible to write plugins for OSX Preview?

Tags: objective-c, macos, plugins, preview

Is it possible to customize OSX Preview application by creating a plugin with Objective-C or other language?

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty certain there is no such thing as plugins for the Preview app.

But to be sure, I did some googling and found this:  https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3296421?start=0&tstart=0

Perhaps you want to write your own QuickLook viewer?

Comment: Where can I find documentation to assess how much in deep I could go in customizing the QuickLook viewer template available in XCode? That is, which methods are available?

Comment: I found [this Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Quicklook_Programming_Guide/Articles/QLProjectConfig.html), which hopefully would help you out?